# HTML5 Session Storage Listener

Tags: html, session-storage

I have a RESTful backend which per definition is stateless. However, I do require authentication. For this, I plan to use Basic HTTP authentication. Since that requires the username and password to be sent with every request, I want to store them clientside.

I was thinking of using the HTML5 session storage for this. The overal browser support is good enough for my application but there is one issue.

I need to catch the event when the session storage is cleared, for instance by closing the tab or clicking the logout button. Before actually clearing the session storage, I need to send the credentials to the RESTful server one last time so it can perform a clean-up operation for that user.

The issue is not so much with the logout button but more so with the tab or browser being closed...

How do I catch this event (with some Listener perhaps?), and delay it from happening until I've made a final REST call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as browser and tab concern you can try following link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload